# Java Parameters on Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: java, spring-boot, dockerfile, kubernetes-deployment

I have a Java/Spring Boot application which is being deployed on K8s Cluster; containerized via Docker.
I'm using Google JIB plugin to create the Docker Image.

While running a Spring Boot app as JAR we can pass JDK parameters along as
`java -jar -Djdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout=120 <JARName>`.

I wanted to know if there is a way to pass the same JDK parameter to a Deployment in Kubernetes. ?
Here are current ENV variable on Deployment.yaml file

```
containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: SERVER_PORT
              value: "8080"
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              value: {{ .Values.profile.active }}
            - name: TZ
              value: America/New_York
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you in a position to change the artifact in the image, or even the entrypoints.sh (or equivalent) script?  I would want to not put this in as a runtime parameter directly unless it could be explicitly controlled by Spring Boot, and not the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

In the K8S pod's spec you can merely define the image being used. This image has already been built and published to the container registry. It is not obvious (or even possible for that matter) how to override the container's `entrypoint`/`cmd` that launches the JVM with specifics args.

What I think you should do instead, is [just use `ENV`/`ARG` in Docker](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-vs-env/) during your CI/CD pipeline. This is exactly what they were designed to solve. This way, you can pass everything you need just during the image build.